# Norm of an operator $T$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

Let $X=(C[0, \pi], \vert \vert . \vert \vert)$. for $f \in C[0, \pi]$ define $T(f)(x)=\int_0 ^x \sin (x+y)f(y)dy$. Find $\vert \vert T \vert \vert$

My answer is $3$. Is it correct?

$\vert \vert Tf \vert \vert_{\infty}=\sup\{\vert \int_0^x \sin(x+y)f(y)dy \vert\}=\sup\{\vert \int_0^x\sin x \cos y f(y)dy+\int_0^x\cos x \sin y f(y)dy\vert\}=\leq \sup\{\vert \int_0^x \cos y f(y)dy\vert\}+\sup\{\vert \int_0^x \sin y f(y)dy\vert\}\leq 3\vert \vert f \vert \vert_{\infty}$

Comment: maybe post your work?

Comment: @Tony S.F., Now check please.

Comment: I am afraid it is wrong. You can get an inequality early on without using any trigonometric identities. This leads in your case to two integrals with trigonometric functions when you were starting with one. (Also, why is the last inequaliy 3 and not 4?)

Comment: @Viertel, if we integrate  $\cos y$ in $0$ to $x$ one of the term is zero. Please help, I am also not sure.

Comment: @Viertel , Please review it , check where it goes wrong.

Comment: @1256 But to get ||f|| out, you have to to put the absolute value inside the integral and therefore you are integrating |cos|. If you change it to 4 it should be correct, however it is not optimal in that you may find a smaller number. I can post the solution (or partial solution) later if you'd like.

Comment: @Viertel, please give a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f \in X$ with $||f||_{\infty} = 1$ and $x \in [0, \pi]$. Then 
\begin{align*}
|Tf(x)| &\leq \int_{0}^x |\operatorname{sin}(x+y)||f(y)|\text{ }dy \\
&\leq \int_{0}^{\pi} |\operatorname{sin}(x+y)|\text{ }dy \\
&=\int_{0}^{\pi} |\operatorname{sin}(y)|\text{ }dy \\
&= 2,
\end{align*}
where the second last equation is true because $|\operatorname{sin}|$ is $\pi$-periodic. So we have already shown $||Tf||_{\infty} \leq 2$ as well as $||T|| \leq 2$.
To show the other inequality we consider the constant function $f \equiv 1$. Then obviously $||f||_{\infty} = 1$ and
\begin{align*}
|Tf(\pi)| &= \Bigg| \int_{0}^\pi \operatorname{sin}(\pi + y)\text{ }dy\Bigg| \\
&= |-2| \\
&= 2
\end{align*} 
and therefore $||Tf|| \geq 2$ which also prooves $||T|| \geq 2$.

So the result is $||T|| = 2$.